How to 'compose' a sport video based on .. action
I'm recording some football game using two "fixed" action cam, starting recording both at the same time.
I'm here to ask you the best approach (if exists) to train a program to take each video section based based on ball's presence on the video, and realize a single video.
So, how to realize a dynamic director based on an object presence ?
Which tool can I use ?
Thanks

